# showing textview on viewpager with delay of time

Tags: android, handlers

I am trying to display text view with 20 seconds delay in a each view page. The view page also display 1 minute delay.means,in each view page i want show three text views, on next page it will show another three text.
please help me out.

```
 private int[] ImageIds={R.drawable.image_asana,R.drawable.image_a,R.drawable.image_c,R.drawable.image_d,
        R.drawable.image_e,R.drawable.end_image};

public static ScreenSlideFragment create(int PageNumber){
    ScreenSlideFragment fragment=new ScreenSlideFragment();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, PageNumber);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
public ScreenSlideFragment(){

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  mPageNumber=getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

  }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final ViewGroup rootView=(ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screenslide_page, container, false);

    ((ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image3)).setImageResource(ImageIds[mPageNumber]);

    if (mPageNumber==ImageIds.length) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(null);

    }


    final Runnable textUpdtae = new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imagetextview)).setText(ImageTextIds[count++]);



        }

    };
    newTimer = new Timer();

    newTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            handler.post(textUpdtae);
        }
    }, 0, 5000);
  return rootView;



}
```

Comment: What errors do you get with this code?

Comment: the error is actually i am having 15 strings when i using settext(count++) after first page its showing the same strings on second page due to it reset counter to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting layoutanimation to viewpager object. This animation will be applied to every view that view pager contains.

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
animation.setDuration(500);
set.addAnimation(animation);
    animation = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 50.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f
);
animation.setDuration(1000);
set.addAnimation(animation);
LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 0.5f);
<ViewPager>.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
```